# PostgreSQL syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have no idea why this error is appearing. The query was working fine and then I tried making it prettier and then this happens

```
UPDATE "topTenCategories" SET "membersCount" =  "tempTable"."newVal" FROM 
    ( 
        VALUES 
        (
            SELECT count(*), "g"."id" FROM 
            "groups" AS "g" 
            LEFT JOIN 
            "groupMembers" As "gm" 
            ON "g"."id" = "gm"."groupId" 
            WHERE "g"."isCategory" is true and "g"."parentCategoryId" is null group by ("g"."id")
        )
    ) AS tempTable ("newVal", "id")
    WHERE "topTenCategories"."groupId" = "tempTable"."id";
```

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 5:                 SELECT count(*), "g"."id" FROM 
                        ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 137
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Or like this ? `with "tempTable" as (
SELECT count(*) as "newVal", "g"."id" FROM 
            "groups" AS "g" 
            LEFT JOIN 
            "groupMembers" As "gm" 
            ON "g"."id" = "gm"."groupId" 
            WHERE "g"."isCategory" is true and "g"."parentCategoryId" is null group by ("g"."id")
)
UPDATE "topTenCategories" SET "membersCount" =  "tempTable"."newVal" 
from "tempTable"
WHERE "topTenCategories"."groupId" = "tempTable"."id";`

Comment: @Philippe this one works, thanks. But what is the issue in my query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put a `SELECT` into a `values` clause like that. The `VALUES` clause is intended for constant values and is not needed here.

```
UPDATE "topTenCategories" 
    SET "membersCount" =  tempTable."newVal" 
FROM ( 
  SELECT count(*), "g"."id" 
  FROM "groups" AS "g" 
    LEFT JOIN "groupMembers" As "gm" ON "g"."id" = "gm"."groupId" 
  WHERE "g"."isCategory" is true 
    and "g"."parentCategoryId" is null group by ("g"."id")
) AS tempTable("newVal", "id")
WHERE "topTenCategories"."groupId" = tempTable."id";
```

You also need to remove the double quotes when you reference `temptable` as the quotes make it case sensitive and `tempTable` is a different name than `"tempTable"`

In general it's highly [recommended](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names) to avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers to begin with.

Comment: thanks a lot. Sadly the system I am working started off with camelCase so I need to follow along.